# A curry function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am new to the functional style, and I wrote a [curry function](http://javascript.crockford.com/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/) to practice this new style. This curry function takes a regular function and returns the curried version of it. Currying is a technique, with which you can partially evaluate functions.

```js
function curry(f, self) {
  return function () {
    if (arguments.length == f.length) {
      return f.apply(self, arguments);
    }
    arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    return curry(f.bind.apply(f, [self].concat(arguments)));
  }
}

function f(a, b, c, d) {
  return this + a + b + c + d;
}

document.write("f(1, 2, 3, 4) = ", curry(f, 0)(1, 2, 3, 4), "<br>");
document.write("f(1, 2, 3)(4) = ", curry(f, 0)(1, 2, 3)(4), "<br>");
document.write("f(1)(2, 3, 4) = ", curry(f, 0)(1)(2, 3, 4), "<br>");
document.write("f(1)(2)(3)(4) = ", curry(f, 0)(1)(2)(3)(4), "<br>");
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Guys, currying is a well known JavaScript technique, you are simply not the target audience ;) I spruced up the question for curious readers.

Comment: I took a quick look on http://javascript.crockford.com/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/. Its solution looks more complicated than mine. Have I missed some use case?

Comment: What is the `self`argument used for? Can't you use `this` if it's not defined? (and allow something like `curry(f)(0)`.

Comment: What's with the `0`? That's not quite equivalent.

Comment: @200_success I guess 0 is the `this` override. @Waterscroll, your implementation is super close to the on here : http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/01/14/gettin-freaky-functional-wcurried-javascript/ I think you are spot on

Comment: If you are interested in functional programming in javascript, you can't do better than [rambda.js](http://ramdajs.com)

Comment: I was trying to follow the same pattern of bind by taking an argument (self) to use as the value for this. I also noticed that carbonfive uses >= instead of == for the arity. I guess this is a better approach because it works with variadic functions better.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit: if you have updated code that you would like reviewed, it's better to ask a new question.  If that's just information for a way to re-write using newer features, I think you could re-phrase that as an answer.  It doesn't really fit in a question that's already answered (it makes the answers look like they are ignoring that version of the code).  I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question,

your code is very close to the code here : http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/01/14/gettin-freaky-functional-wcurried-javascript/

I prefer your lack of `else` since your `if` block has a `return` anyway.

I would name the anonymous function, anything is better than 'anonymous function' when debugging.

```
function curry(f, self) {
  return function curriedFunction() {
    if (arguments.length == f.length) {
      return f.apply(self, arguments);
    }
    arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return curry(f.bind.apply(f, [self].concat(arguments)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  You can save a few chars by doing `arguments = [].slice.call(arguments)`.

Answer (score 1):

I try since yesterday to understand this:

He makes a new copy of f by using bind(). He assigns the parameter already provided but what is with the self.

Let me try to explain:

```
// Second parenthesis (marked with =>): There are three of four  
// expected parameter provided: 
document.write("f(1, 2, 3)(4) = ", curry(f, 0) => (1, 2, 3) <= (4), "<br>");

// Makes an array-literal with 0 as only element in it.
// Then adds the parameter already provided to these array.
// => Must result in an array [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ].
// Then makes a new copy of f with these values bind to it as parameter.
return curry(f.bind.apply(f, [self].concat(arguments)));
```

f should now have it's four parameter. It should be executed and resulting "return 0 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 3;" and return 6.

Why isn't that the case?

Perhaps someone can answer that. I would appreciate it.

Comment: The first argument of bind is used as the value of `this` inside the new function, so the first element of the array passed to apply is going to be used as the value of `this` in the function. The other elements in the array are arguments.